# Docker changing /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff location

Tags: docker, diskspace

Docker folder  /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff grows too much and I would like to move it on an other partition.
Is there a way to configure Docker to use another location for this foder?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's an easy way to get the docker daemon to handle this for you.

stop docker

```
$ service docker stop
```

add this line to /etc/default/docker

```
# Use DOCKER_OPTS to modify the daemon startup options.
DOCKER_OPTS="-g /<new destination>/docker/"
```

start docker

```
$ service docker start
```

verify the docker files and folders are created in the new destination

remove /var/lib/docker

```
/var/lib$ sudo rm -rf docker
```

Comment: This is great. Where did you find this information? I searched for a little while, but could not find any comprehensive documentation for docker_opts

Comment: This moves the whole `docker` directory to a different path - is there a way of migrating **only** one of its subdirectories (`aufs` in this case)?

Comment: This does not work on Systemd, in other words, won't work in recent (>~15.04?) ubuntu or other distros. There's a warning on the file /etc/default/docker "# THIS FILE DOES NOT APPLY TO SYSTEMD"

Comment: It seems `-g` option is deprecated now, use `--data-root` instead (from https://digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-move-the-default-var-lib-docker-to-another-directory-for-docker-on-linux?comment=168943 see comment by mwrochna at September 6, 2021)

Answer (score 3):

There is an answer on [this thread](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3127), basically a ln -s, after some preparatory work

```
docker ps -q | xargs docker kill
stop docker
cd /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt
umount ./*
mv /var/lib/docker $dest
ln -s $dest /var/lib/docker
start docker
```

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3127#issuecomment-30095645