# how to change root dir of docker on ubuntu 18.04 LTS? (docker change location of volumes)

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04

I installed ubuntu 18.04 LTS and checked a setting for docker (17.06.2-ce) to install at the same time.

I tested by starting the hello-world (`sudo docker run hello-world`) :

[...]
Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.
[...]

I mounted a software raid on the folder named `/raid`, and make a folder `/docker-data` in it.

I try to change the root dir of my docker to put it in `/raid/docker-data/` by following the few tutorials on the network... in vain.

[these solutions don't work either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711103/docker-changing-var-lib-docker-aufs-diff-location) :

- `/etc/default/docker` : I can't find this
- As in the 2nd solution : docker can't find his folder.

Docker Root Dir: /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker

Has anyone managed to do this feat in recent months?

(this is my 3rd installation of ubuntu and I just broke it...)

---

Apparently on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, docker 17.06.2-it needs to work with snap, I'm going to dig this way. I will try to return answer later...

Comment: What do you mean by "root dir of my docker"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker changing /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711103/docker-changing-var-lib-docker-aufs-diff-location)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I come back to you to give you the solution that allowed me to solve this problem.

```
cannot perform operation: mount --rbind /var/snap /tmp/snap.rootfs_RRAjdq//var/snap: Permission denied
```

I know why : https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapcraft/+bug/1620771 :

> When /home is a symlink snaps don't work.
>
> When /home is a real directory snaps work, see output below

In my case :

When /raid/snap is a symlink snaps don't work.

When /var/snap is a real directory snaps work.

I deleted docker. I had to reinstall snapcraf (snapd) because I was left on file modifications of it (wrong way)

from there, I stopped the snapd service:

```
sudo mv /var/snap/ /raid/snap
sudo mount --rbind /raid/snap /var/snap
```

I started the snapd service.

```
sudo snap install docker
```

`sudo docker info` <= to test

`sudo docker run hello-world` <= to test

I fixed my mount on fstab:

```
/raid/snap      /var/snap      none      bind
```

I restarted my OS : it worked, at least for my case. (*I checked all along this file consistency handling to see if the docker files was going well on the raid...*)

Answer (score 10):

The common solution is to move the data and create a symlink:

```
systemctl stop docker
mv /var/lib/docker /raid/docker-data
ln -s /raid/docker-data /var/lib/docker
systemctl start docker
```

You can also tell docker about the new location with a setting in /etc/docker/daemon.json. If you don't have this file, you could create one with the contents:

```
{
  "data-root": "/raid/docker-data"
}
```

I would recommend the first solution since you will find many 3rd party tools expect docker to be located in /var/lib/docker.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for this late response.

to come to my problem, after having looked at it more closely:

I am on Ubuntu 18.04, I can add or remove the docker service only via `snap install` (or `remove`) `docker`.

a docker party installs in `/var/snap/`

so I transpose your solution like this:

```
mv /var/snap/ /raid/snap
ln -s /raid/snap /var/snap
```

and finally I install docker via `snap install docker`

I have a test with `sudo docker info`, and I have this error message that appears :

```
cannot perform operation: mount --rbind /var/snap /tmp/snap.rootfs_RRAjdq//var/snap: Permission denied
```

(`snap.rootfs_*`  because the end does not stop changing at each command launch)

and yet the installation went well some docker is apparently of course on `/raid/snap`.

Answer (score 1):

Change Docker root storage (data path):

run this command to find docker data path:

```
$ sudo docker info | grep -i root
```

default path:

```
root@user-testing-HP-ProBook-4540s:/etc/docker# docker info | grep -i root
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
WARNING: No swap limit support
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
```

first, stop the docker:

```
sudo service docker stop
```

copy the corrent data path to new path:

```
sudo rsync -aqxP /var/lib/docker /data/docker-data/
```

add the following on (/etc/docker/daemon.json) file:
(if the file is not there create the file with vim or your fav editor(sudo vim /etc/docker/deamon.json) )

```
{
  "data-root": "/data/docker-data/docker"
}
```

conform with cat command:

```
cat /etc/docker/deamon.json
```

output will be like this:

```
root@user-testing-HP-ProBook-4540s:/home/user/Downloads# cat /etc/docker/daemon.json 
{
  "data-root": "/data/docker-data/docker"
}

root@user-testing-HP-ProBook-4540s:/home/user/Downloads#
```

start docker:

```
sudo service docker start
```

check the root (data path) path now:

```
$ sudo docker info | grep -i root
```

out put will be like this:

```
root@user-testing-HP-ProBook-4540s:/home/user/Downloads# sudo docker info | grep -i root
 

Root Dir: /data/docker-data/docker/aufs
WARNING: No swap limit support
Docker Root Dir: /data/docker-data/docker

root@user-testing-HP-ProBook-4540s:/home/user/Downloads#
```