# Is there way of gaining more root (temporary) volume on the aws sagemaker notebook instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

Aws sagemaker notebook instances come with a fixed root volume size of ~104GB whose ~15 GB is free (available).

Docker uses this temporary memory (`/var/lib/docker` as far as I know).

When I try to build docker image to create custom training-job, temporary root volume in use  blows up and system throws "no space left on the device" error.

I tried to delete anaconda directory (~62 GB), however then, boto3 and sagemaker python libraries stopped working.

What is the best way to solve problem?

Heavy Dockerfile I try to build to push ECR :

```
ARG REGION="us-east-1"

FROM 763104351884.dkr.ecr.$REGION.amazonaws.com/pytorch-training:1.8.1-gpu-py36-cu111-ubuntu18.04

RUN pip3 install torch==1.8.2+cu111 torchvision==0.9.2+cu111 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/lts/1.8/torch_lts.html

RUN python3 -m pip install detectron2 -f \
  https://dl.fbaipublicfiles.com/detectron2/wheels/cu111/torch1.8/index.html

ENV FORCE_CUDA="1"

ENV TORCH_CUDA_ARCH_LIST="Volta"

ENV FVCORE_CACHE="/tmp"

############# SageMaker section ##############

COPY tested_train_src/train_src /opt/ml/code
WORKDIR /opt/ml/code

ENV SAGEMAKER_SUBMIT_DIRECTORY /opt/ml/code
ENV SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM train.py

WORKDIR /

ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "-m", "start_with_right_hostname.sh"]
```

Build command:

```
docker build -t image-name:tag . --build-arg REGION="us-east-1"
```

Output from docker build

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.935GB
Step 1/12 : ARG REGION="us-east-1"
Step 2/12 : FROM 763104351884.dkr.ecr.$REGION.amazonaws.com/pytorch-training:1.8.1-gpu-py36-cu111-ubuntu18.04
1.8.1-gpu-py36-cu111-ubuntu18.04: Pulling from pytorch-training

d2c87b75: Pulling fs layer 
10be24e1: Pulling fs layer 
7173dcfe: Pulling fs layer 
8de7822d: Pulling fs layer 
bf66c36b: Pulling fs layer 
c74d4d18: Pulling fs layer 
f70a70b2: Pulling fs layer 
4e2cb041: Pulling fs layer 
8ddd4da6: Pulling fs layer 
fac38f0d: Pulling fs layer 
a26fd875: Pulling fs layer 
1dca51bb: Pulling fs layer 
0d6bb6c9: Pulling fs layer 
26721764: Pulling fs layer 
956fbe7a: Pulling fs layer 
ad4fa2a5: Pulling fs layer 
20c0bd9a: Pulling fs layer 
82804870: Pulling fs layer 
1d1fdc54: Pulling fs layer 
4500c676: Pulling fs layer 
923bbc02: Pulling fs layer 
0c9d88c6: Pulling fs layer 
f5b0d167: Pulling fs layer 
2f2aa1af: Pulling fs layer 
c272e0bb: Pulling fs layer 
311661aa: Pulling fs layer 
ed3ef379: Pulling fs layer 
03c2d7ac: Pulling fs layer 
1cefc5dc: Pulling fs layer 
30fd2377: Pulling fs layer 
78d30971: Pulling fs layer 
d18f41de: Pulling fs layer 
4c2aeed5: Pulling fs layer 
f099a687: Pulling fs layer 
253573ff: Pulling fs layer 
515cab8b: Pulling fs layer 
056b70c3: Pulling fs layer 
Digest: sha256:66af111d2bd9dae500ad73a7b427103fe8379cbb24bf4ce7cb7d5770d31cd9322KExtracting  505.2MB/962.1MB
Status: Downloaded newer image for 763104351884.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/pytorch-training:1.8.1-gpu-py36-cu111-ubuntu18.04
 ---> b4191cf0b8c9
Step 3/12 : RUN pip3 install torch==1.8.2+cu111 torchvision==0.9.2+cu111 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/lts/1.8/torch_lts.html
 ---> Running in 7c62740a69c6
Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/lts/1.8/torch_lts.html
Collecting torch==1.8.2+cu111
  Downloading https://download.pytorch.org/whl/lts/1.8/cu111/torch-1.8.2%2Bcu111-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl (1982.2 MB)
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

Disk usage before build:

```
sh-4.2$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        1.9G   76K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/nvme0n1p1  104G   89G   16G  86% /
/dev/nvme1n1     63G  1.9G   58G   4% /home/ec2-user/SageMaker
```

Disk usage after erronous build:

```
sh-4.2$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        1.9G   76K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/nvme0n1p1  104G  101G  2.4G  98% /
/dev/nvme1n1     63G  1.9G   58G   4% /home/ec2-user/SageMaker
```

Note : I will try to mount directory `/var/lib/docker` to EBS volume at notebook start.

Note : I don't have any issue about attached EBS volume size. My issue is about temporary volume.

Comment: can you just build the image somewhere else and push to ECR? no need to build on the sagemaker instance

Comment: I will try, however if there is a way of building on the notebook, that would be more convenient. Otherwise I will migrate notebook to external computing resources other than aws or my pc, since I dont wan't to pay for other tasks performed on the notebook. Thank you for advice

Comment: you can change docker root dir in the lifecycle configuration script (tested)."data-root". you will need to enable root access.

Answer (score 7):

I was also facing the same issue. I followed the comments of this post and changed the docker root dir using the following commands.

```
sudo service docker stop
sudo mv /var/lib/docker /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/docker-data
sudo ln -s /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/docker-data /var/lib/docker
sudo service docker start
```

More [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52488300/how-to-change-root-dir-of-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-docker-change-location-of) about changing root dir of docker

Comment: Is there a way to do this for training jobs? Not just for notebooks?

Comment: Note: `ln -s` will create a link inside the folder if it already exists. Therefore check that each command executed without error and `/var/lib/docker` is indeed a symlink.